Linux posix timer cause high total CPU load
I wrote a simple Linux program (timertest) with 500us POSIX timer and running it in Dual-core ARM Cortex-A9 processor. The process timertest takes about 25% CPU load, that's ok. But sometimes the total CPU load is very high (100%). If I kill timertest process, the total CPU load decreased to 1%. I expect the total CPU load is same as timertest process because there is no other high load process running?
I tried with different Linux timer (e.g., setitimer) and top command (e.g., htop, procps-ng top). But it's same result.

Total CPU load is 100% / timertest is 25% (htop)

$ timertest
Busy time: 92 us
posix_timer: 0
posix_timer: 1
...
$ htop
    0[####****************************100.0%] Tasks: 13, 0 thr, 45 kthr; 1 running
    1[#                                 0.7%] Load average: 0.76 0.25 0.09
  Mem[|#*@                       15.3M/1003M] Uptime: 00:02:16
  Swp[                                 0K/0K]

  PID USER       PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU%-MEM%   TIME+  Command
  229 root        20   0  3480  2356  2220 R 25.8  0.2  0:19.73 timertest
  231 root        20   0  3216  2428  1828 R  0.7  0.2  0:00.26 htop
    1 root        20   0  1580  1172  1088 S  0.0  0.1  0:01.68 init [5]
    2 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 rcu_gp
    4 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
    5 root        20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/0:0-rcu_gp
    6 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpr
    7 root        20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/u4:0-events_unboun
    8 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
    9 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 rcu_tasks_rude_
   10 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
   11 root        20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.01 rcu_sched
   12 root        RT   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 migration/0
   13 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 cpuhp/0
   14 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 cpuhp/1
   15 root        RT   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 migration/1
   16 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1
   17 root        20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/1:0-events
   18 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-events_highpr
   19 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
   20 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 netns
   21 root        20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/0:1-events_long
   22 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 khungtaskd
   23 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 oom_reaper
   24 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 writeback
   25 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kcompactd0
   26 root        20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.05 kworker/u4:1-events_unboun
   31 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kblockd
   32 root       -51   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 watchdogd
   33 root        20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.03 kworker/1:1-mm_percpu_wq
   34 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 rpciod
   35 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.05 kworker/0:1H-kblockd
   36 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/u5:0
   37 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 xprtiod
   38 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kswapd0
   39 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 nfsiod
   40 root        20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.04 kworker/0:2-mm_percpu_wq
   41 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 stmmac_wq
   43 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 ipv6_addrconf
   44 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.03 kworker/1:1H-kblockd
   45 root        20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/0:3-events
   46 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 mmc_complete
   47 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 jbd2/mmcblk0p2-
   48 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 ext4-rsv-conver
   51 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/1:2H
   78 root        20   0  2744  1464  1116 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.11 /sbin/udevd -d
   95 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/0:2H-mmc_complete
   96 root        20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/u4:2-events_unboun
  194 root        20   0  2156  1168  1072 S  0.0  0.1  0:03.01 /usr/sbin/dropbear -r /etc
  202 root        20   0  2344  1492  1408 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.01 /sbin/syslogd -n -O /var/l
  205 root        20   0  2344  1512  1408 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.01 /sbin/klogd -n
  209 root        20   0  2100  1180  1084 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
  214 root        20   0  2344  1496  1408 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /bin/sh /bin/start_getty 1
  215 root        20   0  2344  1432  1344 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty1
  217 root        20   0  2432  1684  1556 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.02 -sh
  221 root        20   0  2244  1592  1420 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.25 /usr/sbin/dropbear -r /etc
  222 root        20   0  2432  1680  1556 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.01 -sh


C++ test code (`timertest.cpp`)

#include <csignal>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

namespace {

void busyCpu()
{
    volatile long long i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9000; ++i)
    {
        // Loop 9000: 93 us / CPU 23 %  (Linux arrow-sockit 5.10.100-altera)
    }
}

void posixTimerSignal(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *pri)
{
    static int i = 0;
    static int count = 0;

    busyCpu();
    if (i++ == 2000)
    {
        ::printf("posix_timer: %d\n", count++);
        i = 0;
    }
}

void posixTimerTest()
{
    timer_t timer = {0};
    struct sigevent sev = {0};
    struct sigaction sa = {0};

    const struct timespec timeVal = {
          .tv_sec = 0,
          .tv_nsec = 500 * 1000 // 500 us
    };

    const struct itimerspec its =
    {
        .it_interval = timeVal,
        .it_value = timeVal
    };

    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIGRTMIN;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timer;

    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = posixTimerSignal;

    if(::sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask) == -1)
    {
        ::perror("sigemptyset error");
    }

    if(::sigaction(SIGRTMIN, &sa, nullptr) == -1)
    {
        ::perror("sigaciton error");
    }

    if(::timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timer) != 0)
    {
        ::perror("timer_create error");
    }

    if(::timer_settime(timer, 0, &its, nullptr) != 0)
    {
        ::perror("timer_settime error");
    }

    while (true)
    {
        ::pause();
    }

}

}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::printf("Timer test cpp program started\n");
    posixTimerTest();
    return 0;
}


Linux version:

$ uname -a
Linux arrow-sockit 5.10.100-altera #1 SMP Tue Jun 14 16:39:33 UTC 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux


CPU info

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 200.00
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x3
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 0

processor       : 1
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 200.00
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x3
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 0

Hardware        : Altera SOCFPGA
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000

Update: If I change the timer interval from 500 us to 499 us, the total CPU load is same as process CPU load (24%).

    0[*                            0.7%] Tasks: 13, 0 thr, 41 kthr; 1 running
    1[#######**                   23.8%] Load average: 0.01 0.01 0.00
  Mem[|#*@                  15.2M/1003M] Uptime: 12:03:14
  Swp[                            0K/0K]

  PID USER       PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU%-MEM%   TIME+  Command
  437 root        20   0  3480  2356  2220 R 24.5  0.2  0:01.58 ./timertest -p -
  355 root        20   0  3088  2312  1828 R  0.7  0.2  0:31.52 htop
    1 root        20   0  1580  1172  1088 S  0.0  0.1  0:02.24 init [5]
    2 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.01 kthreadd
    3 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 rcu_gp
    4 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
    8 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
    9 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 rcu_tasks_rude_
   10 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.12 ksoftirqd/0
   11 root        20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.88 rcu_sched
   12 root        RT   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 migration/0
   13 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 cpuhp/0
   14 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 cpuhp/1
   15 root        RT   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 migration/1
   16 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.24 ksoftirqd/1
   19 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
   20 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 netns
   22 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.01 khungtaskd
   23 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 oom_reaper
   24 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 writeback
   25 root        20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:01.16 kcompactd0
   31 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kblockd
   32 root       -51   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.11 watchdogd
   34 root         0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 rpciod


Okay. Do you have a question?

What's the reason for the busyCpu() function? That's probably the reason.

busyCpu() is to simulate time consuming task. Here the loop takes about 90 us at every 500 us timer.

Any ideas? I tried this test program on different HW platform and different kernel options (PREEMPT_RT), always same result. It looks like the total CPU load is spend on context switch?
